# Google Calendar How to fix "You need to have writer access to this calendar"?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, slim

I'm trying to access & write my dummy calendar make new functionality of the website but something prevents me from making changes to my dummy calendar.

So far when I try to used this code:

`$event = $calendar->calendars->get(xxxxxx.com_dsjiub0krm61i5vu1mvee8rh9o@group.calendar.google.com);` 

The result is similar to the Googles Calendar's API explore.

**My Calendar API**

```
$calendarId2 = 'xxxxxx.com_dsjiub0krm61i5vu1mvee8rh9o@group.calendar.google.com';

        $jobname = "Tesla";
        $joblocation = "USA";
        $jobdescription = "Interview with Elon Musk.";
        $startofjob = "2019-03-29T10:00:00.000+00:00";
        $endofjob = "2019-03-30T18:00:00.000+00:00";

        try {
            $client = GetGoogleClient();
            $calendar = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);

            $event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                'summary' => $jobname,
                'location' => $joblocation,
                'description' => $jobdescription,
                'end' => array(
                    'dateTime' => $endofjob,
                    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Manila',
                ),
                'start' => array(
                    'dateTime' => $startofjob,
                    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Manila',
                ),
            ));

            $event = $calendar->events->insert($calendarId2, $event);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e) {
            return ["error" => $e->getMessage()];
        }
```

The message would always say this "You need to have writer access to this calendar." even though I have shared the calendar to the Service Account with permission `Make changes to events` or  `Make changes and manage sharing`

**Additional info**

```
function GetGoogleClient(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    //$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFile);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
    //$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"); //same error result event with or without
    $client->setAuthConfig(CONST_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
    $client->setSubject(CONST_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    return $client;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check that the settings are correct in Google Admin Console. One reason that you would not be able to change the settings on an individual calendar is that the ability to make changes has been restricted on a domain wide basis.

Answer (score 2):

If you are want to use a service account on GSuite organization you have to:

1. login with a Gsuite normal account (also not administrator)
2. create an API Project
3. enable calendar api
4. manage credentials and add a service account
5. download the json authorization file of the service account and copy the client_id in the json file
6. enable domain wide delegation for the service account in the console from the account that created the service account.
7. enable calendar API
8. login with a domain administrator account and go to Google Admin Console and go to Security -> API Controls -> Domain Wide Delegation
9. than add New API Client, insert the client_id at point 4 and the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar (or one from: calendar.events, calendar.events.readonly, calendar.readonly, calendar.settings.readonly)
10. now that service account can impersonate anyone.

This is a sample code:

```
<?php
## composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/* the path of the auth file downloaded from google */
const AUTH_JSON_FILE = 'service-account-test-12345678.json';

/* the subject to impersonate */
const SUBJECT_TO_IMPERSONATE = 'acmeuser@mydomain.com';

/* take calendar id from calendar settings > embed calendar (the default calendar has the same as SUBJECT_TO_IMPERSONATE */
const CALENDAR_ID = "a_abcde123456fghijk789....@group.calendar.google.com";

/* date of the test event*/
const TEST_EVENT_DATE = '2021-01-26';

function getClient() {

    $googleClient = new Google_Client();
    $googleClient->setApplicationName("Anything you want");
    $googleClient->setAuthConfig(AUTH_JSON_FILE);
    $googleClient->setScopes([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR]);
    
    $googleClient->setSubject(SUBJECT_TO_IMPERSONATE);

    return $googleClient;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

/* Create a test event on 2021-01-26 */
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary("Test event title");
$event->setDescription("Test description.....");

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDate(TEST_EVENT_DATE);
$event->setStart($start);

$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDate(TEST_EVENT_DATE);
$event->setEnd($end);

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert(CALENDAR_ID, $event);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

> "You need to have writer access to this calendar."

You may have shared it with the service account but did you give it write access? or just read access?  I think you should double check this its normally the cause of the issue.  Remember this is only going to give it access to this one calendar.

[image]

Also i think you should check your scopes just use

```
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
```

I think they are clobbering each other.  Take a step back make sure calendar works then add your drive stuff

Comment: I did gave permission to the service account set to `Make changes to events` but still the error persist. For some reason sometimes when I add the service account with permission set to `Make changes to events` after how many mins/hrs when I view it again the permission becomes `See all event details` and the other two options are disabled. Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: Not one that i have ever seen I would question if someone else is changing your settings.    Mine has been set for years.